# How to add few indata parameters using gets(tmp)?

Tags: c

```
int regMedicine(Medicine lakemedel[], int antalMedicine)
{
    char namnMed[WORDLENGTH], tmp[WORDLENGTH], test[WORDLENGTH] = "ja";
    int storlek, saldo;

    while(strcmp(test, "ja") == 0)
    {
        printf("Ange namn: ");
        gets(namnMed);
        printf("Ange storlek: ");
        while(tmp!=0){ ///////////////////////
        gets(tmp);          //////////////////////////////////////////
        }               ///////////////////////////////////
        storlek = atoi(tmp); //atoi - converts string to int
        printf("Ange saldo: ");
        gets(tmp);
        saldo = atoi(tmp); //atoi - converts string to int
        lakemedel[antalMedicine] = createMedicine(namnMed, storlek, saldo);
        antalMedicine++;
        printf("Vill du fortsatta registrera (ja) eller (nej): ");
        gets(test);
    }
    return antalMedicine;
}
```

I am writing a program where I use a FILE to register the medicine, size of the medicine and balance.
I wrote a function where I can take the name of medicine, size and balance. But the problem I got stuck is how to add few sizes of medicine and quit by entering "0". Any Ideas? Should I use an extra loop?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Note that without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code it's very hard to suggest anything. Reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is also recommended.

Answer (score 0):

- `gets` is an obsolete function and should never be used. [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)
- `while(tmp!=0)` doesn't make any sense, this checks the target array address against null, which isn't what you want. Instead of this loop, make one checking the result of `fgets`. Examples: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input). You can use `fgets` either on `stdin` (command line input) or directly from the `FILE` pointer.
- Avoid `atoi` since it doesn't handle errors well. Instead use `strtol`, for example `strtol(str, NULL, 10)` where `str` is the string and 10 is decimal format (base 10).
- Avoid writing source code in your native language, since C itself is based on English. It gets confusing when you have to ask for help by English-speaking programmers (such as in this site) and it also gets confusing in general for those reading the code.

  I'm Swedish myself so I can read this, yet the "Swenglish" is much harder for me to read than source code written in pure English. There's also the nasty letters `åäö` which will eventually cause technical problems.

  User messages can of course be in the native language, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

> how to add few sizes of medicine and quit by entering "0". Any Ideas? Should I use an extra loop?

Certainly, if you want to repeat entering size and balance, you'd use a loop, e. g. you could replace

```
        printf("Ange storlek: ");
        while(tmp!=0){ ///////////////////////
        gets(tmp);          //////////////////////////////////////////
        }               ///////////////////////////////////
        storlek = atoi(tmp); //atoi - converts string to int
        printf("Ange saldo: ");
        gets(tmp);
        saldo = atoi(tmp); //atoi - converts string to int
        lakemedel[antalMedicine] = createMedicine(namnMed, storlek, saldo);
        antalMedicine++;
```

with

```
        while (printf("Ange storlek (avsluta genom att ange 0): "),
               fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin) && (storlek = strtoul(tmp, NULL, 10))
              )
        {
            printf("Ange saldo: ");
            if (!fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin)) break;  // leave loop on input end
            saldo = strtoul(tmp, NULL, 10);
            lakemedel[antalMedicine++] = createMedicine(namnMed, storlek, saldo);
        }
```